# Rails mailer with delayedjob not rendering the changes like its cached, deliver_now works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a rails application which I send mails with delayedjob and deliver later, my changes in the view doesnt show up stays like before, when I try it with deliver now it works just fine , I tried Rails.cache.clear in console and tried to set off caching in production.rb though I dont think its relevant

Comment: How do you restart `DelayedJob` after making changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are using to run the jobs in the background does not see your changes after you deploy your application. Usually those are running in separate processes.

Rails on boot loads all files in memory and ignores changes to files in the hard disk.

When deploying, you need to also restart those background jobs (not only the web server) to force it load the new views.

Comment: Yeah thats rights , i deduced it after spickermans comment and you are correct. Bin/delayed_job restart did the trick